# why use $this in below code & if i not use then what happen and using $this what benifit i have?

Tags: php, this

```
class Foo {

    public $Amount = 10;

    public function LoopAmount() {
        for( $x = 1; $x <= $this->Amount; $x++ ) {
            print $x . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

if i can write `$x<=$Amount` then why use `$x<=$this->Amount`, why i use `$this` ,what is the benifties of using $this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit isn't immediately obvious unless you're writing your code with a SOLID architecture, aka Object Oriented Programming.

The point of the `$this` pointer is to refer to a property of an object. This example should make the usefulness more clear:

```
class Person {
  private $eyeColor;
  private $name;
  public function __construct($name, $eyeColor) { //when we create a person, they need a name and eye color
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->eyeColor = $eyeColor;
    //now the person has the properties we created them with!
  }
  public function describe() {
    //and now we can use the person's properties anywhere in the class
    echo "{$this->name} has {$this->eyeColor} eyes.";
  }
  public function setName($name) { //this is called a "setter" or "mutator" study about those!
    $this->name = $name;
  }
}

$Sarah = new Person('Sarah Smith', 'brown');
$Sarah->describe();
//Sarah Smith has brown eyes.

//now, if Sarah gets married and changes her name:
$Sarah->setName('Sarah Doe');
$Sarah->describe();
//Sarah Doe has brown eyes.
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->variable` refers to the value `variable` of a class. Since you are within the class, `$this` refers to `Foo` and you are calling the `Amount` variable of that class.

It comes in handy when calling in the class in another function. Instead of pulling the value out and assigning it to another variable, you just use `$this->Amount`